# Unable to sudo scp with ssh key

Tags: ssh, scp

I need to run a script that contains some instructions which must be run as root, and a scp:

```
sbt assembly # requires sudo
scp -r -p myfile root@myserver.com:/root/spark/root # doesn't require sudo
```

I run it with `sudo python3 ./myscript.py`.

Also, I configured my ssh to communicate with `myserver` using an ssh key:

```
Host root@myserver.com
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
    IdentitiesOnly=yes
    PreferredAuthentications=publickey
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

And I register my ssh key in ssh-agent, in my shell boot script `~/.zshrc`:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/kiliba
```

Note that my public key is effectively registered on `myserver` and that I can ssh or scp towards this server, which means my ssh configuration does work and my ssh key is valid.

However, when using sudo to run this script, the scp keeps asking me for a password, which means my ssh configuration isn't used. It seems to me that I did everything I needed to do in order for scp to work with sudo, but I must be missing something. Note that strangely, while `sudo scp` doesn't work, `sudo ssh` does.

*Funny detail: on another machine I have managed to make it work, however I must've done this a year ago and I am unable to remember what I did for it to work. It's a Mac, and my current machine is on Ubuntu.*

Comment: (1) "I configured my ssh" – Is it global config (in `/etc`)? or user-specific? `sudo scp …` or `sudo ssh …` will not read your *private* config. (2) The tilde in `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey` (if the config applies upon `sudo`) for root means root's home. Are you aware of this? (3) `~/.ssh/mykey` is obviously not `~/.ssh/kiliba`. Which one do you want to use? (4) The whole mechanics of applications using `ssh-agent` relies on the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable. `sudo` sanitizes its environment. What is the output of `sudo env | grep SSH` (after `eval …`)?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski (1) I did it both in ~/.ssh, in /root/.ssh, and in /etc/ssh (not sure whether it's /root or /etc for sudo ssh... but I tried both anyway.). (2) I was not aware of this. I changed the config in /etc and /root for /root/.ssh/mykey instead of ~/.ssh/mykey, and copied my private key to this location, but it still doesn't work. (3) my bad, I misspelled it, it's "mykey". I updated my post. (4) sudo env | grep SSH prints nothing

Comment: @papillon Are you the author of the question? Please see [*I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?*](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) Extra information should be added to the question body, not in comments.

Comment: In `scp … root@myserver.com:…` the server is `myserver.com`. In `Host root@myserver.com` the server is `root@myserver.com`. See the discrepancy? This, along with altering every config and copying the key to another location smells like [voodoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming). Hopefully we will sort it out. (5) Where do you want to store the key? (6) Do you want to use the agent or not? (7) Since `scp` does not require `sudo`, have you considered [running it as your regular user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) from the inside of the script?

Comment: I did create 2 accounts by accident, indeed. I made the request for merging them. Thanks.

Comment: Smells like voodoo indeed, there's a part of what I do that I don't understand. I wish I knew everything I did, but sometimes this is simply not possible to do otherwise.

Comment: OK then. IMO `Host myserver.com` (not `Host root@myserver.com`) is the first thing to try.

Comment: To answer (5) and (6): I don't mind where I store my key or whether I use the agent or not. The only thing that matters is to be able to communicate with the server. I did put the ssh key in the ~/.ssh folder, as I always did, and as everyone seems to do. I'm open to another suggestion ofc. (7) I have considered it but I don't know how to run a script and specify that some operations should be run as sudo and some should not. The only idea I had was running the script as regular user, and entering my password whenever it's necessary, however I would prefer not wasting my time inputting pass

Comment: Add information to the question, not in comments.

Comment: And I would like to insist on the fact that on another machine I am using, I've got no problem running the script. There must be something different at some point but I am unable to figure out what.

Comment: I tried without root@, and adding User root in the block of configuration, but it doesn't help. I don't think writing user@host is a problem

Comment: Ok nvm it works now! Replacing `root@` with a `User root` in the configuration block does solve the problem. I said it didn't because I tried a first time and it didn't work, but I must've tested it incorrectly, I apologize. There is still a mystery though: why does this configuration work on my Mac, and not on Ubuntu? Does ssh on Mac understand that root@myserver is an URI composed of a username and a host, while ssh on Ubuntu thinks the whole string is the server address?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you may write the solution as an answer to the post and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host name should be only the server adress, instead of a uri.

Instead of `root@myserver.com`, I should've written `myserver.com`, and added a rule below to specify the user name:

```
Host myserver.com
    User root
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
    IdentitiesOnly=yes
    PreferredAuthentications=publickey
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```